# problem capturing delimiter with preg_split

Tags: php, preg-split

I have a pipe-delimited dump file from an SQL Server, and I want to import it into MySQL. The lines are delimited by `\r\n`, and that sequence also occurs in some fields! So I want to use a regular expression to find the actual lines and make an `INSERT` statement out of them.

However, I'm having trouble including the delimiter in my match string. I thought using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` would do the trick but apparently I'm doing something wrong. My delimiter is three spaces followed by three numbers, which is actually the id that I need for the row:

```
$ cat test.php
<?
$string = '   897|a|Hello\r\n   583|b|Line\r\nBreak\r\n   332|c|Yet\r\nMore\r\nLine\r\nBreaks\r\n';

$lines = preg_split( '/   \d{3}\|/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($lines);

$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => a|Hello\r\n
    [2] => b|Line\r\nBreak\r\n
    [3] => c|Yet\r\nMore\r\nLine\r\nBreaks\r\n
)
```

My delimiters are missing.

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar 18 2011 17:22:52) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

What am I doing wrong, or how do I get what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to group your delimiter into parenthesis, or else the _DELIM_CAPTURE will have no effect.

```
$lines = preg_split( '/   (\d{3}\|)/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Here, the [manual mentions it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) en passant as flag description:

> **PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE** 
>   If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.

Comment: I had read that, but I didn't understand what parenthesized meant, although its fairly obvious now :P

Comment: OK, that gives me an array with the delimiter being one element and the shard being the next... is there any way to get them as part of the same element? Assertions or something like that?

Comment: No, `preg_split` will only give them out separated. You would have to construct a `preg_match_all` pattern if you wanted them combined.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer will give you delimiter in separate array element.

Check this one instead:
[preg_split how to include the split delimiter in results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758465/preg-split-how-to-include-the-split-delimiter-in-results)