# How do I include the split delimiter in results for preg_split()?

Tags: php, preg-split

I have this simple pattern that splits a text into periods:

```
$text = preg_split("/[\.:!\?]+/", $text);
```

But I want to include `. :` or `!` at the end of the array items.

That is, now for "good:news.everyone!" I have:

```
array("good", "news", "everyone", "");
```

But I want:

```
array("good:", "news.", "everyone!", "");
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here you go:

```
preg_split('/([^.:!?]+[.:!?]+)/', 'good:news.everyone!', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

How it works: The pattern actually turns everything into a delimiter. Then, to include these delimiters in the array, you can use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` constant. This will return an array like:

```
array (
    0 => '',
    1 => 'good:',
    2 => '',
    3 => 'news.',
    4 => '',
    5 => 'everyone!',
    6 => '',
);
```

To get rid of the empty values, use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`. To combine two or more of these constants, we use the bitwise `|` operator. The result:

```
array (
    0 => 'good:',
    1 => 'news.',
    2 => 'everyone!'
);
```

Comment: And what if i need to split "good:" as whole word with the : ?
And can i also add <strong> Tags in? So what i need is <strong>Good:</strong>

Comment: @user1551496: Then you're dealing with markup. Use a parser instead of regex, because [regex can't handle markup well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1230836)

Comment: @NinoŠkopac: `[^.:!?]+` greedily matches all characters except `.:!?` one or more times, the next character group greedily matches `.:!?` one or more times. These two character classes are grouped because the pattern wraps them in `()`, so the result is you match everything. However, the match ends whenever one or more of `.:!?` is encountered, and the next match is set aside in a new group, hence the array -> match, empty, match, empty... using `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`, you ensure the matches used as delimiter are in the array, `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` gets rid of the empty bits

Comment: Essentially, every part in the string is a delimiter, and you're splitting out empty strings. You ignore the empty strings and ask `preg_split` to give you the matched delimiters, which is what the OP was after

Answer (score 12):

No use for `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` if you use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) in your pattern. The function will keep the delimiters.

```
$text = preg_split('/(?<=[.:!?])/', 'good:news.everyone!', 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

If you use `lookbehind`, it will just look for the character without matching it. So, in the case of `preg_split()`, the function will not discard the character.

The result **without** `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag:

```
array (
    0 => 'good:',
    1 => 'news.',
    2 => 'everyone!',
    3 => ''
);
```

The result **with** `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag:

```
array (
    0 => 'good:',
    1 => 'news.',
    2 => 'everyone!'
);
```

You can test it using this [PHP Online Function Tester](http://php.fnlist.com/regexp/preg_split).

Comment: you can also use a positive lookahead  with ?= instead of ?<= so the delimiter would always endup in the next match 'good',':news','everyone!'

Comment: @JonathandosSantos This is handy man. Thanks !