# Regex to get string from last numeric values

Tags: php, regex, string

I have some php string like below

```
abc-1987-mp3-songs
xyz-1999-india-mp3-songs
dec-2001-mp3-songs
ryu-2012-freemp3-songs
```

Now I want these string splited at last found numeric values like below

```
  abc-1987
  xyz-1999
  dec-2001
  ryu-2012
```

Please help me that which regex can be used to do this. thanks.

Comment: actually i dont have any idea to make my own regex.

Comment: split or select....your output is called selection not split

Comment: @way2project: if you want to develop web applications, you're going to have to learn sooner or later: [here](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php), [or here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and of course: google are good places to start. Also know that sites like [this](http://www.functions-online.com) and [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and let's not forget [This one](http://codepad.org/) allow you to practice safely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had a look (do take some time to learn regex - but meanwhile):

```
$split = (preg_split('/(^.*?[0-9]+)\-?[^0-9]+/', 'foo-xyz-1999-india-mp3-songs', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
echo $split[0];//<--- foo-xyz-1999, just like you wanted
```

Dumps an array with `foo-xyz-1999` as first value, which is what you need. If you want to know what every part of the regex does [read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758465/preg-split-how-to-include-the-split-delimiter-in-results/11758732#11758732)

The only difference is that, though the whole string becomes its own delimiter, there are two delimiters (the first part, always ending on a series of numbers and the rest of the string, that doesn't contain any more digits)

Comment: hi Elias Van Ootegem. Thank you very very much. Its working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Do take the time to read the explanation (the link I provided), and look at my comment to your question for links to both tutorials and sandboxes where you can get to grips with regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Use explode insted of regular expression
for example:-

```
$str="abc-1987-mp3-songs";
$f=explode("-",$str);
echo $final_result=$f[0]."-".$f[1];
```

or if you want to use reg exp.then

```
<?php
    $str="abc-1987-mp3-songs";
     echo $f=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $str); 
?>
```

Above code give you all the numeric digits of your string.

Comment: that would only work if the numeric values are always at the second position. He says "last numeric" so I assume there can be multiple occurences...

Comment: no the numeric value can be present at any place like abc-ddd-cerf-1987-mp3-free-songs. I want to spit it at last numeric value found that is like abc-ddd-cerf-1987

Comment: but if you want to use reg exp then see my edited code.but using the reg. exp you will also get the another attached digits like mp3(you also got 3). thats why i am recommended you the explode function.

Answer (score 0):

This would match last occurrence of numeric value from given string:

```
([\w\d-]*-[\d]+)
```

This is the link: [Regex](http://regexr.com?31se5)

[image]

Comment: would it be preg_match or preg_match_all. and could you give me the full regex pattern please. thanks

Comment: this is not working dude in the case of aaa-somthing-abc-1987.it is giving only abc-1987

Comment: It is working fine but how to use this please help. my string is $string and I used preg_match_all("/([\w\d-]*-[\d]+)/g",$string, &$matches);
echo $matches[1]."<br/>";