# Get array of delimiters with preg-split

Tags: php, preg-split

String:

```
"test AND test2 OR test3 AND test4"
```

PHP:

```
preg_split(\s?AND\s?|\s?OR\s?, $string);
```

Result:

```
["test", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
```

Wanted result:

```
["test", "test2", "test3", "test4"]
["AND", "OR", "AND"]
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: With [`PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758465/preg-split-how-to-include-the-split-delimiter-in-results) in between, or rather [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) and capture groups.

Answer (score 2):

A way to separate captured delimiters when `preg_split` is used with the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option.

```
$string = "test AND test2 OR test3 AND test4";

$arr = preg_split('~\s*\b(AND|OR)\b\s*~', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$andor = [];
$test = [];

foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    if ($k & 1)
        $andor[] = $v;
    else
        $test[] = $v;
}

print_r($test);
print_r($andor);
```

`$k & 1` is the bitwise operator AND. When the index `$k` is odd this means that the first bit is set to 1, then `$k & 1` returns `1`. (delimiters have always an odd index except if you use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_split` and `preg_match_all` as

```
$str = "test AND test2 OR test3 AND test4";
$arr1 = preg_split('/\b(AND|OR)\b/', $str);
preg_match_all('/\b(AND|OR)\b/', $str, $arr2);
print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2[0]);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/425182)

Else simply use the answer suggested by [@mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario) using [`PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758465/preg-split-how-to-include-the-split-delimiter-in-results)