# preg_split on regex line start

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to format the following file;

```
[30-05-2013 15:45:54] A A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] B A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] C A
[26-06-2013 14:43:16] Some lines are so large, they take multiple lines, so explode('\n') won't work because
I need the complete message
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] E A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] F A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] G A
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [30-05-2013 15:45:54] A A
    [1] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] B A
    [2] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] C A
    [3] => [26-06-2013 14:43:16] Some lines are so large, they take multiple lines, so 
            explode('\n') won't work because
            I need the complete message
    [4] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] E A
    ...
)
```

---

Based on [How do I include the split delimiter in results for preg_split()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758465/how-do-i-include-the-split-delimiter-in-results-for-preg-split) I tried to use a *positive lookbehind* to persist the timestamps and came up with [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sl4voy/1):

```regex
(?<=\[)(.+)(?<=\])(.+)
```

Which is used in the following PHP code;

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

    class Chat {

        function __construct() {

            // Read chat file
            $this->f = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/testchat.txt');

            // Split on '[\d]'
            $r = "/(?<=\[)(.+)(?<=\])(.+)/";
            $l = preg_split($r, $this->f, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

            var_dump(count($l));
            var_dump($l);
        }
    }
$c = new Chat();
```

This is giving me the following output;

```
array(22) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "["
  [1]=>
  string(20) "30-05-2013 15:45:54]"
  [2]=>
  string(4) " A A"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "
["
  [4]=>
  string(20) "26-06-2013 14:44:44]"
  [5]=>
  string(4) " B A"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "
["
  [7]=>
  string(20) "26-06-2013 14:44:44]"
  [8]=>
  string(4) " C A"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "
["
  [10]=>
  string(20) "26-06-2013 14:43:16]"
  [11]=>
  string(87) " Some lines are so large, they take multiple lines, so explode('\n') won't work because"
  [12]=>
  string(30) "
I need the complete message
["
```

**Question**

1. Why is the first `[` being ignored?
2. How should I change the regex to get the desired output?
3. Why are there sill empty strings with `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`?

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/g5RHWf/1) work for you - `(\[.*?\])([^\[]+)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `preg_split`, you may use

```
'~\R+(?=\[\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}])~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MPjlz9/2)

**Details**

- `\R+` - 1+ line break chars
- `(?=\[\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}])` - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location,requires

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` - a date-like pattern, 2 digits, hyphen, 2 digits, hyphen and 2 digits
  - - a space
  - `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}]` - a time-like pattern, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits.

PHP demo:

```
$text = "[30-05-2013 15:45:54] A A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] B A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] C A
[26-06-2013 14:43:16] Some lines are so large, they take multiple lines, so explode('\n') won't work because
I need the complete message
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] E A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] F A
[26-06-2013 14:44:44] G A";

print_r(preg_split('~\R+(?=\[\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}])~', $text));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [30-05-2013 15:45:54] A A
    [1] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] B A
    [2] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] C A
    [3] => [26-06-2013 14:43:16] Some lines are so large, they take multiple lines, so explode('
') won't work because
I need the complete message
    [4] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] E A
    [5] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] F A
    [6] => [26-06-2013 14:44:44] G A
)
```

Just in case you need to get more details than just split you may use a *matching* approach with

```
'~^\[(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})]\s*+(.*?)(?=\s*^\[(?1)]|\z)~ms'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jhUDeP/1), use it as

```
preg_match_all('~^\[(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})]\s*+(.*?)(?=\s*^\[(?1)]|\z)~ms', $text, $matches)
```

It will match

- `^` - start of a line
- `\[(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})]` - the datetime details (captured into Group 1)
- `\s*+` - 0+ whitespaces (possessively)
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first occurrence of
- `(?=\s*^\[(?1)]|\z)` - the lookahead matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `^` - start of line
  - `\[(?1)]` - `[`, Group 1 pattern, `]`
  - `|` -or
  - `\z` - the very end of string.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks for the details! Do you happen to know if it's possible to split the date and text into an array so? `[0] => [ '[30-...]', 'A A' ]`

Comment: @0stone0 I think I have just answered this question. Just thought you would need that.

Comment: @0stone0 I have come up with a much more efficient version of the second regex, `'~^\[(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})]\h*+(.*(?:\R(?!\[(?1)]).*)*)~m'`, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/jhUDeP/2)

Comment: Works great with speed improvement! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can also use:

```
$text =  file_get_contents("testchat.txt");

preg_match_all('/(\[.*?\])([^\[]+)/im', $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    $date = $matches[1][$i];
    $line = $matches[2][$i];
    print("$date $line");
}
```

Comment: There is a potential problem with this solution, namely, if the text after a timestamp can contain `[` it will stop too early or will split too much, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fefeba/1).