# Bold part of the sentence before certain punctuation in php

Tags: php

From the research I've done this seems to be a very difficult problem, but I'm wondering if anyone has a code snippet they've come up with that does the job.

I have a number of paragraphs that have dashes, colons or periods.  I want to bold the text up until the first punctuation mark of this type.  For example,

Paragraph 1:
**Total precipitation is increasing, primarily as rain.** Between 1901 and 2014, total annual precipitation increased by 7% in the northeastern U.S.

Paragraph 2:
**Frozen ground conditions are more variable and often less frequent:** Temperatures are rising, with the greatest increases occurring during the winter season.

Paragraph 3:
**Earlier spring thaws -** some more text describing this situation.

I tried splitting the string on any punctuation into an array, but then I lose the punctuation in the paragraph when I implode again.

Here is the code I tried:

```
<?php
$s='Frozen ground conditions are more variable and often less frequent: Temperatures are rising, with the greatest increases occurring during the winter season. ';
$sentences=preg_split('/\s*[,:;!?.-]\s*/u', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
?>
<span class="bold"><?php echo $sentences[0]; ?></span><?php echo implode(array_shift($sentences)); ?>
```

I also tried using the css ::first-line, but that bolds more text than I want.

Is there a good way to go about this?

Comment: You 'tried', but you do not show code ?

Comment: Reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Please provide [mre], and not some code which produces: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #1 ($pieces) must be of type array, string given`

Comment: Thanks! @JoeWard.  When I try to use that expression (with a closing ' in the first argument that seems missing) I get an error that 1, 2 and 3 are not defined?

Comment: I was able to use my test code and this question to figure it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758465/how-do-i-include-the-split-delimiter-in-results-for-preg-split

Comment: Apologies. Deleting previous. Replacing with:

$para = preg_replace('/(^.+?\:)([\s\w,]+)(.+)/', "$1<strong>$2</strong>$3", $para);